# Como verificar se existe determinado ID no banco de dados?

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo validações antes de importar um arquivo .csv para o banco de dados via C# , ja fiz uma validação para garantir que o codigo estado seja um inteiro e preciso tambem verificar se existe o codigo estado que esta vindo no .csv exista realmente cadastrado no meu banco de dados...como posso fazer isso ? aqui esta meu metodo que faz as validaçoes:

```
DataTable dt = CriaDataTable();
using (StreamReader arquivo = new StreamReader(caminho))
{
    string linhaArquivo;
    string[] campos;
    DataRow registro;
    bool cabecalhoJaLido = false;

    while (!arquivo.EndOfStream)
    {
        linhaArquivo = arquivo.ReadLine();

        if (!cabecalhoJaLido)
        {
            cabecalhoJaLido = true;
            continue;
        }

        campos = linhaArquivo.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        registro = dt.NewRow();
        try
        {
            bool resultNumero;
            int numero;

            resultNumero = int.TryParse(campos[4], out numero);
            registro["Numero"] = numero;

            if (!resultNumero)
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
                Label1.Text = "Campo numero não esta vindo como valor inteiro";
            }

            bool resultTipoPessoa;
            int tipoPessoa;

            resultTipoPessoa = int.TryParse(campos[2], out tipoPessoa);
            registro["TipoPessoa"] = tipoPessoa;

            if (!resultTipoPessoa || tipoPessoa > 1)
            {
                Label2.Visible = true;
                Label2.Text = "Campo Tipo Pessoa com valor inválido";
            }

            bool resultEstado;
            int estado;

            resultEstado = int.TryParse(campos[7], out estado);
            registro["Estado"] = estado;

            if (!resultEstado)
            {
                Label3.Visible = true;
                Label3.Text = "Campo Codigo Estado não esta vindo como valor inteiro";
            }

            if (campos[0].Length > 70)
            {
                registro["Nome"] = "";
                Label4.Visible = true;
                Label4.Text = "Campo Nome excedendo limite de caracteres";
            }
            else
            {
                registro["Nome"] = campos[0].ToString().Trim();
            }

            if (fgCpfCheck(campos[1]) == false)
            {
                registro["Documento"] = "";
                Label5.Visible = true;
                Label5.Text = "CPF Inválido";
            }
            else
            {
                registro["Documento"] = campos[1].Trim().ToString();
            }

            if (campos[3].Length > 100)
            {
                registro["Endereco"] = "";
                Label6.Visible = true;
                Label6.Text = "Campo Endereco excedendo limite de caracteres";
            }
            else
            {
                registro["Endereco"] = campos[3].Trim().ToString();
            }

            if (campos[5].Length > 20)
            {
                registro["Complemento"] = "";
                Label7.Visible = true;
                Label7.Text = "Campo Complemento excedendo limite de caracteres";
            }
            else
            {
                registro["Complemento"] = campos[5].Trim().ToString();
            }

            if (campos[6].Length > 60)
            {
                registro["Bairro"] = "";
                Label8.Visible = true;
                Label8.Text = "Campo Bairro excedendo limite de caracteres";
            }
            else
            {
                registro["Bairro"] = campos[6].Trim().ToString();
            }

            if (campos[8].Length > 100)
            {
                registro["Cidade"] = "";
                Label9.Visible = true;
                Label9.Text = "Campo Cidade excedendo limite de caracteres";
            }
            else
            {
                registro["Cidade"] = campos[8].Trim().ToString();
            }

            if (campos[9].Length > 10)
            {
                registro["CEP"] = "";
                Label10.Visible = true;
                Label10.Text = "Campo CEP excedendo limite de caracteres";
            }
            else
            {
                registro["CEP"] = campos[9].Trim().ToString();
            }

            if (Label2.Visible == false)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(registro);
            }
            else
            {
                Label11.Visible = true;
                Label11.Text = "Operação não realizada!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Estou passando esse metodo de cima para esse outro metodo...que ele sim vai acessar o banco e importar o arquivo .csv

```
public void ProcessarImportacao(string caminho)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MC1_DB_TREINAMENTOConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conexao.Open();

                using (SqlBulkCopy bc = CreateSqlBulkCopy(conexao))
                {
                    bc.WriteToServer(RetornaDtPreenchido(caminho));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Dê mais informações. Que tecnologia está usando para acessar o banco de dados? Você quer que o `resultEstado` seja localizado? Como está estruturado seu DB? Ajude-nos ajudar você.

Comment: No meu DB tenho uma tabela Estado com 19 estados , ou seja o codigo estado que esta vindo no arquivo .csv tem de ser um deles...estou usando SqlBulkCopy para gravar esse arquivo no Banco...entendeu mais ou menos ?

Comment: Evite o uso de tags HTML na resposta. Para formatar como código, basta selecionar com o mouse e apertar o ícone `{ }`. Para mais detalhes, leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possível solução seria:

```
int resultEstado = int.TryParse(campos[7], out estado); 
registro["Estado"] = estado;

if(!resultEstado) 
{ 
    Label3.Visible = true; 
    Label3.Text = "Campo Codigo Estado não esta vindo como valor inteiro"; 
}
else
{
    //abre conexao com o banco
    //faz a operação com o banco passando o campo 
    //id registro["Estado"]

    if(dr.HasRows())
    {
        Label3.Visible = true; 
        Label3.Text = "Campo Codigo Estado já existente no banco de dados"; 

    }
    else
    {
        // faz o insert
    }
}
```

Caso você tenha dúvidas de como fazer a operação com o banco responda ai que eu te ajudo.

Att.

Comment: Então na verdade eu to passando esse metodo para outro metodo que esse sim vai grava o arquivo .csv no banco de dados esse metodo aqui oh: public void ProcessarImportacao(string caminho)
        {
  using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MC1_DB_TREINAMENTOConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conexao.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy bc = CreateSqlBulkCopy(conexao))
                {
                    bc.WriteToServer(RetornaDtPreenchido(caminho));
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @Daniel: quando quiser adicionar mais informações à questão, por favor, edite-a. Assim todas as informações ficam reunidas no corpo da mesma.

Comment: Certo , me desculpe é o meu primeiro dia aqui

Comment: Então Daniel, você faz o desvio de fluxo para verificar o id no banco, como você já esta fazendo. Se sua condição primaria é saber se o registro que vem do .csv está no banco para assim adicionar ou não no banco faça o desvio já no começo e caso o id exista no banco, siga para o próximo registro em seu .csv. Se não ficou claro me ajude a entender a sua dúvida. Att.